# Wordpress website links only work on page refresh or with cache disabled

Tags: wordpress, caching, browser-cache

Since yesterday links on my website only work if I click them and then refresh the page. On the first click the addressbar shows the correct address, but the content doesn't change. htaccess is unchanged and there are no cache plugins installed atm. There is no cache directory in /wp-content/ and the webserver cache has also been cleared. If I disable caching in DevTools or visit the website while beeing logged in in Wordpress the pages load correctly. Browser cache has also been cleared.

What is wrong with my website? Thank you!

Comment: Test disabling all plugins. Clear the browser cache and re-test. Then preview/activate Twenty17, repeat the test. What are the results?

Comment: @David.J Both didn't change anything, the problem persists when changing the theme. When I changed the theme and then cleared the cache and closed the browser I still had to refresh the page to see the new theme.

Comment: Are you able to share a link?

Comment: Can you re-save your permalinks? Clear your cache and re-test?

Comment: @David.J Already did that and just did it again, but nothing changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178184/discussion-between-david-j-and-myusername).

Comment: @niclaszll Did you solve this, I've exactly the same problem and it's driving me nuts...